# Why do I get 'This computer name is already in use on this network' prompt?

Tags: system-installation, ubiquity, hostname

I was installing 16.04 Desktop on a HP laptop yesterday, and when it came time to enter my name, username etc, most suggestions I had for the computer name generated a warning that 'This computer name is already in use on this network.', and I could not proceed with the installation without choosing something else.

There's only one Ubuntu VM on my LAN, and no other machines using vaguely similar names. I had connected to my wireless network and allowed updates during installation, but surely it's not checking every computer name in the world!

Why did this happen, and how can I make sure I can use a computer name of my own choosing?

Comment: This only happens if you have an exact match within your local network so either rename the Ubuntu-VM or change the name of the machine you want to install.

Comment: @Videonauth I tried 14 different names, there are only 9 devices on my LAN. It just doesn't add up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the name conflict prevented you from going on with the installation?

I had the same warning last week when upgrading my systems, since i used the same names they used before I also got the warning (I think it comes from a DNS lookup), but it did not stop me from continuing at all, all I had to do was ignore the warning and click to continue.

Comment: Thinking about it, it was getting kinda late, so I may have presumed that the installation wouldn't continue. I'll give it a go later, and upvote/accept your answer if I can continue.

Comment: Btw, some ISPs redirect invalid DNS lookups to a custom page instead of returning a DNS error. If the installer was checking names using DNS, every single (invalid) name would generate the warning when connected to such ISP. Try typing any invalid name on your browser and check if you get a page from your ISP, or an error from the browser itself.