# Why can't I use the same host name for two dual-boot OS on the same machine?

Tags: networking, dual-boot, hostname

I run Win 10 (installed first) and Ubuntu 16.04 (installed second) on the same notebook.

During the Ubuntu installation, I was asked to enter a host name for the computer. I tried to enter the same host name I configured in Windows, but got an error message that this host name is already in use in the current network.

The above happened to me on my previous notebook as well.

Why does Ubuntu know what host name the dual-boot Windows installation uses, how can I avoid this error in the future and how can I give it the same host name anyway?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you install without connecting the computer to your router?

Comment: I think I did not try that (and don't plan to reinstall at the moment). It always was connected to the router I assume.

Comment: I am not sure, but it may be that Ubuntu performs a NS lookup for the hostname and the router cached the response so it finds a hit even though Windows is switched off.

Comment: Btw, you can always change the name at a later point by entering `sudo hostname NEWNAME`. To make the change permanent, edit `/etc/hostname`

Comment: I had a similar issue, but as answered here http://askubuntu.com/a/786486/320386 it's just a warning at the installation stage, and you can use the hostname regardless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have the same host name in each OS in a multi-boot system. However, if you are connecting to the network, your DHCP server may still have an active lease for that name, and Ubuntu tries to obtain a DHCP lease using the name you enter. If an active lease already exists, you may see the error you are getting.

You can open your router or DHCP server's config and clear the lease table, and that should free up use of the name to install with it. Alternatively, you can install using a different name and change it after.

Comment: I'd go for the first option (clearing the table). This will make ubuntu accept the same name so you keep the same lease when switching OS after.